# can't find maxUserPort registry editor

Tags: registry

Where it is maxUserPort?
I have searched in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

but no result.
[image]

Any help please?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you've selected Parameters in the picture, only expanded the tree.

Comment: I edited and still..

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938196.aspx), MaxUserPort is supposed to be a Double Word (REG_DWORD).

Right click in the empty white space below currently listed registry entrys, expand the New menu and click on DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name the new value MaxUserPort.

Comment: Yeah, but I was trying to modify the existing maxUserPort, not to create one.

Comment: The default value is 5000. If you bothered to look at the link that I sent you, you would see that it says "Windows 2000 does not add this entry to the registry. You can add it by editing the registry or by using a program that edits the registry." This probably also applies to later versions of Windows.